# Error installing Cuda toolkit: Existing package manager installation of the driver found

Tags: cuda, gpu-driver

I'm working with Ubuntu 16 and [Cuda toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) 10.2.

I'm using installer file: cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run.

I understand I need to remove something I previously installed but don't know what exactly.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect to need to remove a previously installed package? What was that package? Which Ubuntu is installed;  16.04 or 16.10 ? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: I just got the same message. Just in case anyone wonders, right after "driver found," the messages says something like "YOU ARE STRONGLY ENCOURAGED TO ABORT." So that explains the 'need to remove a previously installed package...'

Answer (score 23):

If you only want to install the cuda toolkit to /usr/local, please run:

```bsh
sudo sh ./cuda_10.2.<spec>.run --toolkit --silent --override
```

If you need nvidia driver as well, you could try the answer provided by Albino Cordeiro

> Running dpkg -l | grep Nvidia and then sudo apt purge ... did the trick.

Warning: above will uninstall your current nvidia driver.

Answer (score 11):

Just run into this exact problem in Ubuntu18.04. And after some search, my solution is the following:

1. If you are sure that your driver version matches the cuda-toolkit version you are gonna install, refer to @domainxz answer, add `--toolkit` to only install toolkit and not to care about nvidia driver.
   Check [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) link for compatibility. (Scroll down to CUDA Driver table).
2. If you want CUDA to handle the compatibility problem for you, you need to uninstall your current drivers.
   Follow the instructions in [the official documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile).
   After you entered the text screen after reboot, uninstall your previous Nvidia driver and run the cuda runfile. For Ubuntu 18.04, what I did and worked:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia\*
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo sh cuda-*.run --silient --override
```

The official documentation is actually very detailed... Just make sure you follow each step and you should be fine.

Comment: I had to purge the following patterns as well: `\*nvidia\*`, `\*cuda\*`, `\*nvrtc\*`

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve my problem. I manage a large number of identical servers and usually use a .run file (cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run) to install the Cuda toolkit. On this one specific server, I did some experiments a while ago and forgot that I installed the previous version of Cuda differently there (using `sudo apt install`). Running `dpkg -l | grep Nvidia` and then `sudo apt purge ...` did the trick.

Comment: did you mean - dpkg -l | grep nvidia

Comment: purge what?....

Comment: purge cuda, so you can install the newer version using the .run file.

Comment: I get a list of 25 lines (e.g., nvidia-cuda-dev, libnvidia-common-440...) you mean purge all?

Comment: In my case, that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

got in rootm with

```
$ sudo su
```

then

```
# for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $3}'); do dpkg-divert --remove $FILE; done
```

then

```
# apt --fix-broken install
```